# Overriding shipping.html file in custom module

Tags: shipping, magento2.3, shipping-methods, html

I am trying to override shipping.html file to my custom module, but it's not working for me.

**requirejs-config.js**

```
var config = {
paths: {        
    'Magento_Checkout/template/shipping': "Vendor_Namespace/template/shipping",
}
};
```

**shipping.html**

```
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->

<li id="shipping" class="checkout-shipping-address" data-bind="fadeVisible: visible()">
    <div class="step-title" translate="'Shipping Address'" data-role="title" />
    <div id="checkout-step-shipping"
         class="step-content"
         data-role="content">

    <each if="!quoteIsVirtual" args="getRegion('customer-email')" render="" />
    <each args="getRegion('address-list')" render="" />
    <each args="getRegion('address-list-additional-addresses')" render="" />

    <!-- Address form pop up -->
    <if args="!isFormInline">
        <button type="button"
                class="action action-show-popup"
                click="showFormPopUp"
                visible="!isNewAddressAdded()">
            <span translate="'New Address'" />
        </button>
        <div id="opc-new-shipping-address"
             visible="isFormPopUpVisible()"
             render="shippingFormTemplate" />
    </if>

    <each args="getRegion('before-form')" render="" />

    <!-- Inline address form -->
    <render if="isFormInline" args="shippingFormTemplate" />
</div>
</li>

<!--Shipping method template-->
<li id="opc-shipping_method"
class="checkout-shipping-method"
data-bind="fadeVisible: visible(), blockLoader: isLoading"
role="presentation">
<div class="checkout-shipping-method">
    <div class="step-title"
         translate="'Shipping Methods'"
         data-role="title" />

    <each args="getRegion('before-shipping-method-form')" render="" />

    <div id="checkout-step-shipping_method"
         class="step-content"
         data-role="content"
         role="tabpanel"
         aria-hidden="false">
        <form id="co-shipping-method-form"
              class="form methods-shipping"
              if="rates().length"
              submit="setShippingInformation"
              novalidate="novalidate">

            <render args="shippingMethodListTemplate"/>

            <div id="onepage-checkout-shipping-method-additional-load">
                <each args="getRegion('shippingAdditional')" render="" />
            </div>
            <div role="alert"
                 if="errorValidationMessage().length"
                 class="message notice">
                <span text="errorValidationMessage()" />
            </div>
            <div class="actions-toolbar" id="shipping-method-buttons-container">
                <div class="primary">
                    <button data-role="opc-continue" type="submit" class="button action continue primary">
                        <span translate="'Next'" />
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
        <div class="no-quotes-block">
             <!-- ifnot="rates().length > 0"
             translate="'Sorry, no quotes are available for this order at this time'" >-->
            <button type="submit" class="button"><span translate="'Request a quote'" /></button>
         </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </li>
```

Comment: Please mention path of your shipping.html

Comment: app/code/vendor/namespace/view/frontend/web/template/shipping.html

Comment: @Pratikojha did you try my answer below?

Comment: @magefms yes i did, but not worked for me. is there any xml that is also reuired to override for this?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? your expected output? why do you want to override it?

Comment: @magefms i want to add an button in the <div class="no-quotes-block">
             <!-- ifnot="rates().length > 0"
             translate="'Sorry, no quotes are available for this order at this time'" >-->
            <button type="submit" class="button"><span translate="'Request a quote'" /></button>
         </div>    if there is no shipping method

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite your **`requirejs-config`** like below:

```
var config = {
    "map": {
       "*": {       
        'Magento_Checkout/template/shipping': "Vendor_Namespace/template/shipping"
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 ways to achieve that:

> 1) Using theme :

```
app/design/frontend/Vendorname/Theme/Magento_Checkout/web/template/shipping.html
```

> 2) Using extension :

```
app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/view/frontend/web/template/shipping.html

app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

var config = {
    paths: {
        'Magento_Checkout/template/shipping': 'VendorName_ModuleName/template/shipping'
    }
};
```

Comment: but i have to do using extension, please tell me is there any other required file for this.

Comment: I don't think so, have you clear the cache, pub/static and generated folder?

Comment: yes i tried everything.

Comment: I am also trying to override this shipping.html, however it seems nothing appear, any idea why? I did empty cache too

Comment: Im having this issue too

Answer (score 0):

How to override both shipping.html and shipping.js

Create file **requirejs-config.js** in following path

> app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

Paste Below code

```
var config = {
    paths: {
         'Magento_Checkout/template/shipping': 'VendorName_ModuleName/template/shipping',
         'Magento_Checkout/js/view/shipping': 'VendorName_ModuleName/js/view/shipping'
      }
};
```